# Does GridView automatically append values “ASC” or “DESC” to the value of sortExpression parameter?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, ado.net

When GridView implements sorting, does it automatically append string values “ASC” or “DESC” to the value of sortExpression parameter? If so, then based on what criteria does it “decide” when to append “ASC” and when to append “DESC” value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does.  Clicking the same column multiple times in a row toggles the sort between ASC and DESC.  See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.allowsorting.aspx) for more info.

> Clicking the link button for a column
>   causes the items in the GridView
>   control to be sorted based on the sort
>   expression. Typically, the sort
>   expression is simply the name of the
>   field displayed in the column, which
>   causes the GridView control to sort
>   with respect to that column. To sort
>   by multiple fields, use a sort
>   expression that contains a
>   comma-separated list of field names.
>   You can determine the sort expression
>   that the GridView control is applying
>   by using the SortExpression property.
>   **Clicking a column's link button
>   repeatedly toggles the sort direction
>   between ascending and descending
>   order.** To determine the current sort
>   direction, use the SortDirection
>   property.

Comment: Assuming current sort direction is set to SortDirection.Descending, then only way to change the current sort direction is to handle GridView.Sorting event and manually change the sortExpression string by replacing its substring "DESC" with substring "ASC"?

Comment: No - if you want to change it from the Sorting event - use the GridViewSortEventArgs to do it (e.SortDirection) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewsorteventargs.aspx

Comment: sorry for not replying sooner, but I didn't notice your reply.Anyways, I really appreciate your help